# Unit Test Angular Form Validation With $validators

Tags: angularjs, validation, unit-testing, jasmine

My webapp is using **Angular 1.4.8**. I have a directive that validates a form input using **$validators**. Only input that starts with number 5, 6 and 9 and contains 8 numbers are valid.

```
angular
    .module('directive.customNumber', [])
    .directive('customNumber', customNumber);

function customNumber() {
    var REGEXP = /^([569][0-9]{7})/;

    return {
        require: ['ngModel', '^form'],
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$validators.customNumber = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
                if(ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
                    // consider empty models to be valid
                    return true;
                }
                return REGEXP.test(viewValue);
            };
        }
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
<form name="form">
    <input type="text" name="myInput" custom-number>
</form>
```

Now I want to write a unit test for this directive using **Jasmine**. This is my test case:

```
describe('Directive', function() {
    var $scope;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('directive.customNumber');
        inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
            $scope = $rootScope;
            var template = '<form name="form"><input type="text" name="myInput" custom-number></form>';
            $compile(template)($scope);
            $scope.digest();
        });
    });

    it('should not accept invalid input', function() {
        var form = $scope.form;
        form.myInput.$setViewValue('abc');

        expect(form.$valid).toBeFalsy();
        expect(form.myInput.$error.mobile).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

Running this throws an error `"TypeError: Cannot set property 'customNumber' of undefined` at this line:

```
ctrl.$validators.customNumber = function(....
```

I am not sure why `$validators` become undefined in the test but works fine in normal environment. Even if I get rid of this error by manually creating `$validators` object before use, the test fails because the `customNumber` validator is never being run (know by logging), so `form.$valid` is always true.

**How can I properly test this directive?**

Comment: I think that your ctrl is an array where ctrl[0] is the ngModel and ctrl[1] is the formController

Comment: Or could be because $digest is triggered twice as you are inside the inject function. I believe i already had this problem before.

Comment: @Raulucco Simply changing all access from `ctrl` to `ctrl[0]` works! I have also tested $digest, it seems that it is unrelated to my issue here. You can post the answer and I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I posted it at first but then I was confused because you said that worked on the normal env. I'm glad to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your directive ctrl is an array whare ctrl[0] is the ngModel and ctrl[1] is the formController